# Schedule in different time zone

Tags: python, django, timezone, celerybeat

I'm developing a `Django` project.

I want to sync classes automatically.

**My code:**

```
from datetime import timedelta
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'sync-classes': {
    'task': 'scheduler.tasks.sync_classes',
    'schedule': crontab(hour='0', minute=0),
}

CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
```

It works in the London time zone.

Each class has a different time zone. I want the schedule to run automatically based on the relevant time zone of classes.

In `sync_classes()` method I get all classes and sync it in London Time zone.

**Question:** How can I sync every class based on its time zone?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the *timezone of classes*? Do you store a timezone on your models? Like... `user.timezone` or something? Also, that task runs every midnight (London TZ), right? What would you like it to happen with your classes?

Comment: @BorrajaX I stored time zone in the class model. the task runs every midnight. Now every class run in London time zone. But it should run in its time zone (should run in class.timezone).

Comment: I don't think you can do that with Celery... Not exactly (that `CELERY_TIMEZONE` only means that when you tell it *run this task at midnight*, that is *midnight in London*. I suggest you run the task every hour, for instance (instead of every day as it's doing now) and within the task get the timezones that would be in midnight at that moment, and sync the objects whose timezone is in those timezones.

Comment: @BorrajaX is there any way to sync the task at exact midnight for all the time zones?

Comment: No. Firstly, you're not guaranteed that your entry (your class) is going to be visited at exactly midnight. Also, timezones are messy. You have some timezones that have offsets in the half of the hour, or even in the :45th of the hour (such as Nepal)

Comment: @BorrajaX Okay. Thanks Bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is untested when it comes to the Django/Celery part, but here's the idea:

1. Change your Celery-Beat's schedule to run every 15 minutes. That should pretty much cover [all the TZ offsets in existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) because most are either multiples of hour, or multiples of half an hour, with only a few cases being multiples of a quarter of hour (so this 15 minutes resolution should cover *all* the timezone offsets of the world):

   ```
   CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
       'sync-classes': {
       'task': 'scheduler.tasks.sync_classes',
       'schedule': crontab(minute='*/15'),
   }

   CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False   
   CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
   ```

   At this point, Celery's timezone doesn't matter because we're gonna use the only *decent* timezone as a reference: UTC.
2. Create an auxiliary function that will give you the names of the timezones in which **now** (*"now"* meaning *"when your task is run"*) is "*almost*" midnight. Your task will run every 15 minutes... Maybe a few milliseconds after the 15 minutes mark... so let's give it 10 minutes of buffer (that should be way, **way** more than enough). As long as the buffer is less than 15 minutes, you should be fine (*fine* meaning that you won't have one task and the next thinking that *"now"* is midnight and therefore running the synchronization twice)

   This should help:

   ```
   import pytz
   import datetime

   utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
   collected_tz_names = []
   for tz in pytz.all_timezones_set:
       test_dt = utc_now.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz))
       print("tz: %s, test_dt.time() %s" % (tz, test_dt.time()))
       is_midnight = (
           datetime.time(hour=0, minute=0, second=0) <=
           test_dt.time() <=
           datetime.time(hour=0, minute=10, second=0)
       )
       if is_midnight:
           collected_tz_names.append(tz)
   print("collected %s" % collected_tz_names)
   ```

   If you want to test it, change the `utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow())` "probe" (or reference) to a few manual values, such as `utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=1, day=4, hour=4, minute=1, second=0)`)
3. Once you've collected the timezones in which *`now`* is *midnight* in the `collected_tz_names` list, run your sync method. Let's say the objects you need to synchronize are the `User`(s), right? And that your `User` model has an attribute `tz_name` that indicates which is the timezone of each user. In that case, this should do:

   ```
   for user in User.objects.filter(tz_name__in=collected_tz_names):
       user.synchronize()
   ```

Keep in mind that in *Daylight savings times* switches, you might end up synchronizing twice.